# return of generic when trait is not implemented

Tags: generics, rust

Here is the code I've been struggling with for a while

```
use ethers_providers::{Provider, Http}; //, JsonRpcClient};

// this doesn't work
// trait ClientGeneric<T> {
//     fn get_client(&self, url:&str) -> Provider<T> {
//         Provider::<T>::try_from(url).unwrap()
//     }
// }
// this works but I want generic
trait ClientConcrete {
    fn get_client(&self, url:&str) -> Provider<Http> {
        Provider::<Http>::try_from(url).unwrap()
    }
}
struct Test;
impl ClientConcrete for Test {}

#[cfg( test )]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    // #[test]
    // fn test_get_client_generic() {
    //     let test = Test{};
    //     let client = test.get_client("http://localhost:8080");
    // }
    #[test]
    fn test_get_client_concrete() {
        let test = Test{};
        let client = test.get_client("http://localhost:8080");
    }
}
```

I want to return `Provider<T>` for every single transport T: http, ws, ipc, mock, etc
Generally every transport has a TryFrom trait implemented. However the code above won't work with generic T even though it works with concrete transports. The error I get for generic T:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Provider<T>: From<&str>` is not satisfied
 --> src/test.rs:6:9
  |
6 |         Provider::<T>::try_from(url).unwrap()
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&str>` is not implemented for `Provider<T>`
  |
  = help: the following other types implement trait `TryFrom<T>`:
            <Provider<Http> as TryFrom<&'a String>>
            <Provider<Http> as TryFrom<&str>>
            <Provider<Http> as TryFrom<String>>
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<Provider<T>>` for `&str`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<&str>` for `Provider<T>`
```

Unfortunately there is no match statement over type T I could use (as in Golang) to go to concrete types implementations.
As I understand I can not implement foreign trait `TryFrom<&str>` for foreign struct `Provider<T>`. `TryFrom<&str>` is implemented for underlying types `Http`, `Ws`, `Ipc`, etc

Is there anything else I could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your generic function that doesn't compile:

```rust
fn get_client(&self, url:&str) -> Provider<T> {
    Provider::<T>::try_from(url).unwrap()
}
```

The reason it does not compile is due to `T` not having any bounds specified. If this compiled, it would mean the function could create a `Provider<T>` for *any* `T`. But that's not possible; as you note only certain types like `Http` work for `T`, because `Provider<Http>` implements `TryFrom<&str>`. So you need to provide these necessary bounds so the function can compile.

This is how I'd write it:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

use ethers_providers::Provider;

trait ClientGeneric<T>
where
    for<'a> &'a str: TryInto<Provider<T>>,
    for<'a> <&'a str as TryInto<Provider<T>>>::Error: Debug,
{
    fn get_client(&self, url: &str) -> Provider<T> {
        url.try_into().unwrap()
    }
}

impl<T, U> ClientGeneric<U> for T
where
    for<'a> &'a str: TryInto<Provider<U>>,
    for<'a> <&'a str as TryInto<Provider<U>>>::Error: Debug,
{
}

struct Test;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_get_client_generic() {
        let test = Test {};
        let _client = test.get_client("http://localhost:8080");
    }
}
```

Note I opted to use `TryInto` instead of `TryFrom`, though either would work fine in this case.

The first bound lets us call `try_into()` to convert the `&str` into a (`Result`-wrapped) `Provider<T>`:

```rust
for<'a> &'a str: TryInto<Provider<T>>
```

The second bound is just needed so the `.unwrap()` method works:

```rust
for<'a> <&'a str as TryInto<Provider<T>>>::Error: Debug
```

In real code you should probably avoid unwrap though, and instead return a `Result`.

Comment: Amazing! Learned a lot. Thank you! If it works fine, will accept the answer

Comment: quick follow up if possible. I need to constraint the error type of the result to `Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`.  Box is type not a trait. What is the right syntaxis?

Comment: @Nikolay You need to convert the error type; see this gist: https://gist.github.com/Seeker14491/3e566ed1e5714ae013296996ce69732e